# How to remove row from datatable within specific id in bottom line

Tags: c#

The code below choose the first row and remove the other row below with specific id.  The things that i want is the last line within the id.

```
var dtremove = RemoveDuplicateRows(dt, "id);
```

This the extension

```
 public DataTable RemoveDuplicateRows(DataTable dt, string colName)
        {
            Hashtable hTable = new Hashtable();
            ArrayList duplicateList = new ArrayList();


            //Add list of all the unique item value to hashtable, which stores combination of key, value pair.
            //And add duplicate item value in arraylist.
            foreach (DataRow drow in dt.Rows)
            {


                if (hTable.Contains(drow[colName]))
                {

                    duplicateList.Add(drow);

                }
                else
                    hTable.Add(drow[colName], string.Empty);
            }

            //duplicateList.Sort();


            //Removing a list of duplicate items from datatable.
            foreach (DataRow dRow in duplicateList)
                dt.Rows.Remove(dRow);

            //Datatable which contains unique records will be return as output.
            return dt;
        }
```

The example of datatable.

```
id    date
------------
A    1/1/2018
A    1/2/2018
A    1/3/2018
B    2/1/2018
B    2/2/2018
```

i want the result like this.

```
id    date
------------

A    1/3/2018
B    2/2/2018
```

Comment: What have you tried and how is the behavior different than the expected behavior? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can use Linq but first start writing some code.

Comment: i already update the codes

Answer (score 0):

I tried not to change too much of your code, pretty sure it can be improved, but the changes below looks for the value and if it already exists in the dictionary, it replaces it: Thus, you will end up with the very last row instead of the first one. Also, it returns a new `DataTable` and the original one will stay intact.

```
public DataTable RemoveDuplicateRows(DataTable dt, string colName)
{
    var uniqueRows = new Dictionary<string, DataRow>();
    foreach (DataRow thisRrow in dt.Rows)
    {
        if (uniqueRows.ContainsKey(colName))
        {
            uniqueRows[colName] = thisRrow;
        }
        else
        {
            uniqueRows.Add(colName, thisRrow);
        }
    }

    DataTable copy = dt.Copy();
    copy.Rows.Clear();
    foreach (var thisRow in uniqueRows)
    {
        copy.Rows.Add(thisRow.Value);
    }

    //Datatable which contains unique records will be return as output.
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: At copy.Rows.Add(thisRow); , it show error such : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.Data.DataRow]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.Couldn't store <[id, System.Data.DataRow]> in id Column.  Expected type is Int64.

Comment: @mharry sorry see edit. You need to use `copy.Rows.Add(thisRow.Value);`

Comment: Another problem occur at copy.Rows.Add(thisRow.Value); which is this row already belongs to another table.

Comment: Okay i got it instead of using add row i just use ImportRow.